# Namespace problem while loading XAML dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application that load a FlowDocument from a embedded resource, with the following code

```
object something = XamlReader.Load( stream );
```

The parser tell me he cannot find the "clr-namespace:ReportPrinter" at

```
<FlowDocument
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:c="clr-namespace:ReportPrinter"
>
```

A quick search with google tell me i need to specify the assembly, but how i can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply append the name of the assembly containing the specified class to the definition of the namespace. A good example of the correct string can be found at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx#Y1140). There is also a description about the different possibilities to describe a certain assembly.